# L'emploi familier de « malade » pour « génial » est-il usuel en position d'épithète etc. ?

Tags: adjectifs, registre-familier, emprunts

L'emploi familier de « [malade](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/malade) » pour « génial, excellent, qui sort de l’ordinaire » est-il usuel en position d'épithète :

> Je suis allé voir un concert hier, c'était malade. → Un concert malade.
> Hein, c’est malade comme idée, il faut absolument qu’on le fasse un jour. → Une idée malade.
> ...cet oiseau de proie vraiment [*sick*](https://twitter.com/jfrobergeQc/status/1635968367726063618)/malade est reconnu...

Incidemment, le fait qu'un oiseau puisse être atteint d'une maladie empêche-t-il un emploi clair avec ou sans l'adverbe *vraiment* et l'emprunt « [sick](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sick) » est-il alors utile dans ce contexte et ce registre ?

Comment: Personnellement je ne l'entends jamais utilisé comme ça. Toujours "*de malade*".

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Oui, *C'était un concert de malades !*

Answer (score 3):

Non, malade dans le sens de génial n'est jamais utilisé en tant qu'adjectif épithète. Normalement, on dit *un truc **de** malade* (*une idée, un concert de malade* pour reprendre vos exemples) et non *un truc malade*.